# How do I view the owner of a Vertica table?

Tags: vertica

I have a table in Vertica that I can't drop, because I'm not the owner.  How do I see who the owner of the table is?

Comment: Are you a superuser? [Changing the table owner](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HTML/index.htm#17909.htm).

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I'm not.

Comment: Try this: https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HTML/index.htm#16392.htm

Comment: @kevingessner Feel free to reach out to me [directly](http://vertica.tips/contact/) if you have any questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're not the owner of the table, or do not have have privileges to see the table, then you most likely won't be able to see who the owner is:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, owner_name FROM v_catalog.tables;
```

[Documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/TABLES.htm)